# Merge and Sort two arrays maintaining relative order

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have two arrays A & B `{1,2,1,2}` and `{2,1,2,1}`.

I want to sort them in such a way the that after the arrays are merged and sorted looks like this,

`1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1`

The relative order of A and B is maintained!

Can this be done using,
    `std::sort()`?
If not which method would you suggest?

more clarification,

Let the indices of array A be `1,2,3,4` and of B be `-4,-3,-2,-1`
Now I must not lose the order of index of array A and array B but merge them together such that number of contiguous elements in the merged array is minimized,

Another example,
`{3,4,4,5}` and `{7,8,4,9,5}` is sorted as,

`{3,7,8,4,4,9,5,5}`
We can see that the number of groups of contiguous identical elements here is

'3', '7' ,'8' ,'4 ,4' ,'9' ,'5, 5'

I tried a solution but not with `std::sort()`.I declared a variable which maintains the next insert position so for each number from array B I loop through the elements and search whether its present in A or not and insert it in the next "insert" position.

Comment: Your ordering criterion is not well-defined. That said, this looks like an XY problem. What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @Dúthomhas Im trying to group identical elements from both the arrays and achieve an optimal solution that gives me fewer identical contiguous groups.

Comment: But you are not grouping identical elements -- a standard sort would make N groups of elements where there are N distinct elements. This is "optimal". What about your grouping is different?

Comment: In the context of your original problem, would it make sense to group related items into a class? If you don't know about classes, you should definitely learn about them. Creating a class will allow you to create a single array of items.

Comment: @SathyaramGanapathy Can you be more specific about your ordering criteria or if you can provide some more examples

Comment: @Dúthomhas Yes, Like the condition said, the relative order should be maintained.So if not standard sort, can you suggest any other method?

Comment: @Ishpreet Yes one more added,guess my question is more clear this time.

Comment: You still have not provided a concrete sort order. Why are those 4s grouped after 7 and 8?

Comment: @SathyaramGanapathy I guess you are just merging the two array by keeping their relative order same, There's no *sort* involved here. If you are solving a specific problem, It would be more helpful if you can provide a link

Comment: @Dúthomhas '7' and '8' is from another array and also '4,4' is a group I don't want to lose the groups or else my merged array would contain more identical contiguous groups of elements. For example 3,4,4,7,8,9,5,5 is also a solution to this problem if you say.

Comment: Ok, this is looking more and more like a topological sort. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Ishpreet You can say Im interleaving the arrays and making maximum possible such groups.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I'm not aware of topological sort. So you say if I read an article about it I would be able to achieve this kind of re-arrangement?

Comment: Yes, a topological sort gives you exactly the kind of answer for the _second_ example, but not the first. A topological sort for the first will produce either 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2 or 2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the sort of code that you are looking for?

```
vector<int> a = {1,2,1,2};
vector<int> b = {2,1,2,1};
vector<int> result;
int i  = 0;
for (; i < min(a.size(),b.size()); i++){
    result.push_back(a[i]);
    result.push_back(b[i]);
}
if (i < a.size()) {
    result.push_back(a[i]);
} else if (i < b.size()){
    result.push_back(b[i]);
}
```

Comment: Since I got notified of this post again after a long time, I had to recollect the problem I was trying to solve with the answer to my question. I was basically trying to interleave (preserve order) two lists such that the maximum number of integers with the same value get grouped together. I then realized the problem is more than just sorting/merging the lists and I must use Dynamic Programming to calculate the Longest Common Subsequence and then group it together in that way. Thanks for trying to solve my short puzzle!